# $.ajax xml status 200 but error

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax, xml

I use jQuery.ajax() request to my server and get xml response. for some reasons some users get the error. status code is 200 but we proceed to the error handler :-( at the moment I can not find any consistent pattern. For ex I can get a "wrong request url" from my user and try it on my device after that - and it works! so the problem is not with the url.

Request code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myserver.com/oauth.php?token="12345",

    // whether this is a POST or GET request
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    dataType : "xml",

    success: function( response ) {
        console.log('parsing XML response');
        ...
        return true;
    },

    error: function( xhr, status ) {
        console.log("error status " + status);
    },
});
```